# Python - Why doesn't this prime number checking algorithm work?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

I have this python code that I wrote:

```
from math import *

limit = 100000
primes = [2]

for i in range(3, limit+1, 2):
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(3, floor(sqrt(i)), 2):
        if i % j == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime: primes.append(i)

print(len(primes))
```

It says there are 9676 primes less than 100 000, when it should be 9592. It gives the correct answer if I the replace `floor(sqrt(i))` with just `i`, but then it's terribly slow. Why doesn't my algorithm work?

Comment: Hint: look at your `for j in ...` line, and try `print(list(range(3, floor(sqrt(25)))))` at a Python prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take, for example `i == 9`. The following range:

```
for j in range(3, floor(sqrt(i)), 2):
```

Evaluates to:

```
for j in range(3, 3, 2):
```

...which is an empty list, preventing non-prime 9 from being ruled out. You need to go one higher to ensure that the root of square numbers is considered:

```
for j in range(3, floor(sqrt(i)) + 1, 2):
```

Answer (score 4):

You're including primes that are squares of other primes - I changed the sqrt range definition in your code to get:

```
from math import *

limit = 100000

primes = [2]

for i in range(3, limit+1, 2):
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(3, floor(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
        if i % j == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime: primes.append(i)

print(len(primes))
```

resulting in 9592 primes found